# Interfaces inside database class for declaring table and column names - good approach?

Tags: android, database-design, interface, sqliteopenhelper

Instead of using `final String`s for declaring table and column names inside a database class, does approach of using inner `interface`s is a good approach. It looks like this:

```
public class MyDb extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //... fields, constructor,etc.

    interface Tables {
        String T1 = "t1";
            String T2 = "t2";
        //etc.
    }

    interface T1Columns {
        String T1_ID = "t1_id";
        String Column1 = "c1";
        String Column2 = "c2";
        //etc.
    }

    //other data

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
          db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Tables.T1 + " ("
               + Columns.T1_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
              //etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people consider the [Constant Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface) to be an anti-pattern. It certainly works, but I find just as much success doing something like this:

```
public final class Entity {
    public static final String TABLE = "table_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_1 = "column1_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_2 = "column2_name";
}
```

To me it seems cleaner and more proper to encapsulate the information of each entity separately.

Comment: This is a standalone class right? Because of the `public`. Not an inner class?

Comment: It could be an inner class (and still be public).

Comment: On the link you posted, there is intriguing sentence after the talk on the anti-patter. It says `Note that the Java libraries use constant interface pattern themselves, proving that it may be a reasonable choice in some situations.`

Comment: I don't know that it really makes a difference, as long as you can use your table and column names where they are needed.